# anchor download attribute specification

Tags: jquery, html

Is there anyway to allow a user to download just part (DIV) of file.html not the whole file. If so, how to specify it in href attr.

```html
<a download href="file.html" ></a>
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem ... what exactly are you trying to do? There is no partial download without server code behind it

Comment: I just want to extract a part of file.html and put it in a new html file and make available to the user to download it.

Comment: Will need server script to do that or if it's a static partial create different file yourself

Comment: I am new at this. I am trying to dynamically change a part of a file and make downloadable. is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: Already explained how you would do it.